# Как в Xcode добавить кастомную команду в меню при выделении кода?

Tags: ios, swift, xcode

Хочу добавить свою команду(сортировку строк) в меню, когда наживаешь правую кнопку мыши на выделенном код, но не знаю как это сделать и гугление не помогло - не нашел, скорее всего не правильно искал. Подскажите, пожалуйста, куда смотреть или может как правильно загуглить.

[image: Меню]